# How can I write data by method response.write after got from MySQL server to a Node.js program?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, node.js, http

I'm developing a small web app by NodeJS and I'm stuck at this point. Please review my code:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    if (path=='/ajax.html') {
        displayData(function(result) {
             console.log('Result' + result);
             response.write(result, 'utf8');
        });
    }
});


function displayData(callback) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : config.host,
        user     : config.user,
        password : config.password,
        database : config.database,
    });
    connection.connect();
    var query = connection.query("SELECT name FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'");  
    query.on('result', function(row) {
        callback(row.name);
    });
}
```

I tested and realised that the response object in `displayData` is not itself anymore so that I am just able to view my result data in console.log and can not use response.write to view it in browser.

Please help what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [`response.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) once you've finished writing data to it.

Comment: Yes I did and on my work, I can use response.write to write any content to browser. That method works fine until response object in displayData function. Just only this point got issue.